# adding callback on colorbox to skip the first image of slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Weird requirement, but I want to skip only the first slide on my slideshow (made with colorbox). So basically, what I want is that the first slide doesn't show and slideshow opens with the second slide.

The only way I can think of achieving it through doing the "go next" on "onLoad" function but I am not sure how to make it go next only for first image.

This is what I have done:-

```
$(".element").colorbox({
    onLoad:function(){
        $.colorbox.next();
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, even "next()" is not working. I am not sure how to achieve that. Any idea how to achieve it through this or may be some other way?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just remove the first slide from the page?

Comment: It's generating through CMS. I wish I could do that.

Comment: So `remove()` it with jquery before instantiating the colorbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I like Rob's idea to `$.remove` the element more than the idea below but if your heart is set on not mucking up the CMS' DOM...

I'm not sure but this may be a scope thing:

You could try binding the event to the DOM:

```
$(document).on('cbox_complete', function(){
  $.colorbox.next();
});
```

(I would try with the complete event first and then experiment from there)